# Creating multiple rank columns dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df with several columns, and I'd like to rank them. I can do them one at a time like this:

```
iris.ranked <-
  iris %>% 
  arrange(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = rank(Sepal.Length))
```

But there are lots of columns...and this is clunky. I'd rather feed a list of columns and rank them all in one code chunk. I was thinking something like this but not working...

```
iris.ranked.all <-
  iris %>% 
  mutate_at(
    c('Sepal.Length',
      'Sepal.Width',
      'Petal.Width',
      'Petal.Length'),
    function(x) arrange(x) %>% rank()
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mutate(across())` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
iris  |>
    mutate(
        across(
            Sepal.Length:Petal.Width, 
            rank, 
            .names = "rank_{.col}")
    )
# # A tibble: 150 x 9
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species rank_Sepal.Length rank_Sepal.Width rank_Petal.Length rank_Petal.Width
#           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>               <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>
#  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa               37              128.               18                 20
#  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa               19.5             70.5              18                 20
#  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa               10.5            101                 8                 20
#  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa                7.5             89                31                 20
#  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa               27.5            134.               18                 20
#  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa               49.5            146.               46.5               45
#  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa                7.5            120.               18                 38
#  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa               27.5            120.               31                 20
#  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa                3               52.5              18                 20
# 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa               19.5             89                31                  3
# # ... with 140 more rows
```

Or if in fact you want to overwrite the columns as your question suggests, omit the `.names` argument:

```r
iris  |>
    mutate(
        across(
            Sepal.Length:Petal.Width, 
            rank)
    )
```

Comment: this is great. how would one reverse the ranking?

Comment: @pyll replace `rank` with an anonymous function `\(x) rank (-x)`

Comment: Ah ok thanks so much, and thanks for the reminder about the new pipe! I've got to start using that one.

Comment: it doesn't really matter which you use - i just use Fira Code font and the new pipe looks really nice